# Convert seconds to hhmmss Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a UDF that creates a timestamp out of 2 field values with date and time. However, the field with time is of seconds format.
So how сan I merge 2 fields of type date and seconds into an hour of a type Unix timestamp?

My current implementation looks like this:

```
private val unix_epoch = udf[Long, String, String]{ (date, time) =>
    deltaDateFormatter.parseDateTime(s"$date $formatted").getSeconds
  }

def transform(inputDf: DataFrame): Unit = {
  inputDf
    .withColumn("event_hour", unix_epoch($"event_date", $"event_time"))
    .withColumn("event_ts", from_unixtime($"event_hour").cast(TimestampType))
}
```

Input data:

```
event_date,event_time
20170501,87721
20170501,87728
20170501,87721
20170501,87726
```

Desired output:

```
event_tmstp, event_hour
2017-05-01 00:22:01,1493598121
2017-05-01 00:22:08,1493598128
2017-05-01 00:22:01,1493598121
2017-05-01 00:22:06,1493598126
```

Update. data schema:

```
event_date: string (nullable = true)
event_time: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `event_date` to a unix timestamp, add the `event_time` column to get `event_hour`, and convert back to normal timestamp `event_tmstp`.

PS I'm not sure why `event_time` has 86400 seconds (1 day) more. I needed to subtract that to get your expected output.

```scala
val df = Seq(
    ("20170501", 87721),
    ("20170501", 87728),
    ("20170501", 87721),
    ("20170501", 87726)
).toDF("event_date","event_time")

val df2 = df.select(
    unix_timestamp(to_date($"event_date", "yyyyMMdd")) + $"event_time" - 86400
).toDF("event_hour").select(
    $"event_hour".cast("timestamp").as("event_tmstp"),
    $"event_hour"
)

df2.show
+-------------------+----------+
|        event_tmstp|event_hour|
+-------------------+----------+
|2017-05-01 00:22:01|1493598121|
|2017-05-01 00:22:08|1493598128|
|2017-05-01 00:22:01|1493598121|
|2017-05-01 00:22:06|1493598126|
+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I have updated the question and added the data types. With this approach I get an error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTimestamp`

Comment: @Cassie that's weird, the whole code works on my machine with SPark 3.0. Can you try the edited code? I also tested it to work on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code if this helps without `UDF`

```
val df = Seq(
     (20170501,87721),
     (20170501,87728),
     (20170501,87721),
     (20170501,87726)
).toDF("date","time")
```

```
df
.withColumn("date",
        to_date(
            unix_timestamp($"date".cast("string"), 
            "yyyyMMdd"
        ).cast("timestamp")
    )
)
.withColumn(
    "event_hour",
    unix_timestamp(
        concat_ws(
            " ",
            $"date",
            from_unixtime($"time","HH:mm:ss.S")
        ).cast("timestamp")
    )
)
.withColumn(
    "event_ts",
    from_unixtime($"event_hour")
)
.show(false)
```

```
+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|date      |time |event_hour|event_ts           |
+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|2017-05-01|87721|1493598121|2017-05-01 00:22:01|
|2017-05-01|87728|1493598128|2017-05-01 00:22:08|
|2017-05-01|87721|1493598121|2017-05-01 00:22:01|
|2017-05-01|87726|1493598126|2017-05-01 00:22:06|
+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
```